# Find all xml elements in XmlSchema having XmlSchemaType

Tags: c#, xsd

Having given xmlType:=XmlSchemaType (.NET class), how can I find all types in its XmlSchema having elements of xmlType?

I'm looking for something like xmlSchema.FindAllTypesOfType(xmlType) regardless of depth, i.e. xmlType can be child of a xmlSchema root elements or grandchild - anywhere.

Comment: The two paragraphs seem to be asking for two different things. Please check that your wording is accurate - the function name FindAllTypesOfType sounds wrong. Ideally, please supply an example XSD with your expected output.

Comment: FindAllTypesOfType is pseudocode - what's wrong? But I can update the question.

Comment: What's wrong? In XML Schema, a type does not have a type. So I suspect that you are being careless with your wording. If you use the words that the XML Schema specification uses, everybody will understand your question.

Comment: Xml Schema cab have simple or comlex types. Complex types can be defined either in the same schema or referenced from another schema. So I need to find all comlex types referencing given type definition.